# Odd Primes Problem Proof

Tags: prime-numbers

**Given** the odd prime numbers,

**Prove** that if $x$ and $y$ are adjacent odd primes in this list, then $x + y$ has $3$ prime factors. The factors need not be distinct.

Here is an example I have provided:
$3 + 5 = 8 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$. Therefore, $8$ has $3$ repeated factors of $2$.

Comment: By odd adjacent primes do you mean the neighbouring odd primes? .... Yeah actually I think you do, forget that I asked.

Answer (score 6):

If $x$ and $y$ were consecutive odd primes then $x+y = 2z$ for some integer $z$. If $z$ was a prime that would make $z$ lie between $x$ and $y$ which is not possible since $x,y$ are consecutive primes. Hence, $z$ has atleast two prime factors (not necessarily distinct).

Comment: I think it would be much better not to answer questions at this level that show no effort.

Comment: @WillO That is what you think. Not every body thinks that asking for showing effort is not an stupid idea.

Comment: @WillO isn't it a better idea to encourage the user asking the Q to show efforts first than discourage users from answering them ? :-)

Comment: Yeah, the show-effort army is "that rational".

Comment: Sciona:  I think that discouraging users from answering them is prerequisite to encouraging effort.

Comment: @WillO: Thanks, I misread adjacent as twin.

Comment: @Sciona:  Plus, this seems to be a particularly egregious case since the comment on Meelo's answer indicates that the OP hasn't stopped to think about this question for an instant.

Comment: @WillO It is not your job. You are not anybody's daddy. It is their own decision the amount of effort each one want's to put on a problem.

Comment: @Pp..  Yes.  and it's my own decision how I want to respond to that.

Comment: @WillO Andre's comment 'Multiplicity 4.' is ambiguous. When we talk about multiplicity of a prime dividing $p$ dividing $n$, we are looking for the highest power of $p$ in prime factorization of $n$. He possibly meant number of prime factors is $4$.

Answer (score 3):

$$11+13=24=2^3\cdot 3\,\,\,\,$$

Comment: Multiplicity $4$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How can I prove that?

Comment: @mathemagician:  You're asking how to prove that $3+1=4$ ?????

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x<y$ are adjacent odd primes. Then $x+y = 2a$, $a\in\mathbb{Z}$.

$x<y \Rightarrow 2x<x+y<2y \Rightarrow 2x<2a<2z \Rightarrow x<a<y$

How $x$ and $y$ are adjacent primes, then $a$ is not prime. Suppose $a=b\cdot c$, with $b, c>1$.

So $x+y = 2\cdot b\cdot c$. Therefore $x+y$ has **at least** 3 prime factors